# How to make Vite development server serve images in nested folder

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm working on a React app, using **Vite**. Once I **build** the app, I have no problem seeing the images, but during **development**, I get the following error in the browser:

```
GET https://localhost:5173/uploads/2/6337005fd6d4d.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Images are supposed to be served from a folder at `public/uploads`. The `favicon.ico` at `public` isn't being served either (during development).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer to my own question: In `vite.config.js`, I had to set the [root](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root) of the project, and the [publicDir](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory), which by the way, must be set relative to the `root`.